# Number of ways of selecting $4$ people out of $12$ sitting on a round table such that no two of them are consecutive

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Indexing the people as $x_i$ where $i\in(1,2,\cdots,12)$

So, each choice of $x_i$ must differ atleast by one and hence they are the solution to the equation.

$x_1+1+x_2+1+x_3+1+x_4+1=12$
Which by the stars and bars  method is $\binom{7}{3}$ which is apparently not correct, where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Please do not change a question after it has been answered since that has the effect of invalidating existing answers (such as the one true blue anil posted just before you edited your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will solve the problem for a line first, then form a circle by joining the ends of the line.  However, we will have to correct for the case where people at both ends of the line are selected since they will become adjacent when we form a circle by joining the ends of the line.

We will first arrange eight blue and four green balls in a line so that no two of them are consecutive.  Line up the eight blue balls in a row.  This creates nine spaces in which to place the green balls.
$$\square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square$$
To ensure that no two of the green balls are consecutive, choose four of these nine spaces in which to place the green balls, which can be done in $\binom{9}{4}$ ways.  If we now number the balls from left to right, the numbers on the green balls represent the people who have been selected, no two of whom are consecutive.

However, if we place green balls at both ends of the row, then the people in those positions will be adjacent after the ends of the row are joined to form a circle.  Therefore, we have to subtract those selections in which no two of the green balls are adjacent and both ends of the row are selected.
$$g b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square b g$$
If we place green balls at both ends of the row, then we must choose two of the interior seven spaces in which to place the other two green balls, which can be done in $\binom{7}{2}$ ways.

Hence, the number of ways to select four people at a round table where twelve people are seated so that no two of them are adjacent is
$$\binom{9}{4} - \binom{7}{2} = 126 - 21 = 105$$

**What did you do wrong?**

You need a reference point, such as the top of the table.  You then have to consider two cases, depending on whether the person at the top of the table is selected.

*The person at the top of the table is selected*:  Let that person be the first selected person.  Let $x_1$ be the number of people between that person and the second person who is selected as we proceed around the table in the clockwise direction; let $x_2$ be the number of people between the second selected person and the third person who is selected as we proceed around the table in the clockwise direction; let $x_3$ be the number of people between the third selected person and the fourth selected person as we proceed around the table in the clockwise direction; let $x_4$ be the number of people between the fourth selected person and the person at the top of the table.  Since no two consecutive people are selected,
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 8 \tag{1}$$
is an equation in the positive integers.  A particular solution of equation $1$ corresponds to the placement of $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs in the seven spaces between successive ones in a row of eight ones.
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
The number of solutions of equation 1 is the number of ways we can place $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs in the $8 - 1 = 7$ spaces between successive ones in a row of eight ones, which is
$$\binom{7}{3}$$

*The person at the top of the table is not selected*:  Let $x_1$ be the number of people before the first person who is selected as we proceed clockwise around the table from the top of the table; let $x_2$ be the number of people between that person and the next selected person as we proceed clockwise around the table; let $x_3$ be the number of people between the second selected person and the third selected person as we proceed clockwise around the table; let $x_4$ be the number of people between the third selected person and the fourth selected person as we proceed clockwise around the table; let $x_5$ be the number of people between the fourth selected person and the top of the table.  Since the seat at the top of the table is not occupied and no two of the people are consecutive,
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 8 \tag{2}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers with $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 > 0$ and $x_5 \geq 0$ (since the last person could have been selected).  If we let $x_5' = x_5 + 1$, then $x_5'$ is a positive integer. Substituting $x_5' - 1$ for $x_5$ in equation $2$ yields
\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5' - 1 & = 8\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5' & = 9 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation $3$ is an equation in the positive integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of $5 - 1 = 4$ addition signs in the $9 - 1 = 8$ spaces between successive ones in a row of nine ones, of which there are
$$\binom{9 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{8}{4}$$

Since these two cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, there are
$$\binom{7}{3} + \binom{8}{4} = 35 + 70 = 105$$
ways to select four people from twelve people sitting at a round table so that no two consecutive people are adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

idk why you think that your changed equation will lead to a correct solution. One way to get the answer is:

"un number" the $x_is$, take out $4$ "tokens",
insert back into the $9$ interstices (including the ends)
in $\binom94$ ways, renumber the "tokens"

Each of the $\binom94$ renumberings represents valid positions.

**Note**
You changed the question afterwards: anyway, having got a solution to the "row" version, can you now at least show your effort for the "round" version ?

**PS:**

You ask $\binom84$ ways for the round table ? Not quite.
Form four blocks (clockwise, say) of one "normal" sitter and one "separate" sitter, ie $\boxed{NS},\;$ so the four "separate" sitters can never be together.

You now have $8$ **entities**, four $N$ + four $\boxed{NS}$, which can apparently be arranged in $\binom 84$ ways, *but each entity is only getting $8$ "starting points" instead of the $12$ they would normally get*, so multiply by $\frac{12}8$ to get $\frac{12}8\binom84 = 105$ ways.

Comment: I'm so sorry the title was wrong earlier

Comment: See my Note and try. It shouldn't be difficult now.

Comment: There will be only 8 interstices now so, the answer should be $\binom{8}{4}=280$ ?

Comment: @ParthShresth $\binom{8}{4} = \frac{8!}{4!4!} = \frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4!}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 4!} =  1 \cdot 7 \cdot 2 \cdot  5 = 70$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig ah yes my bad

Comment: You have already received an answer for the "round" case. However, I'm adding a different way shortly.